Find a Substring in String with Boardtools is not working if the string contains special chars
Today I got frustrated. I'm implementing a very simple logic with substring finding; it turned out to be a more complex situation.
Let's consider this small python code:
word_one, word_two = ['(/ %$ss%*++~m/()', 'ss?=)?=)()']
field_content = "5uz8439qvnhfruieoghbvui gfurieaogv ui(/ %$SS%*++~m/() 123456789651321654 'ss?=)?=)() 87788+#~~##+"
pos_word_one = field_content.index(word_one)
pos_word_two = field_content.index(word_two)
print(pos_word_one) # throw an ValueError but the substring is included
print(pos_word_two) # 74

Does someone have an idea? Is the encoding important, or does it help here? With regex, we will have more problems because then I need to auto-escape all these special characters.

What is your actual question? What is Boardtools?

There is nothing like word_second variable in the program.
The substring word_one contains uppercase characters (%$SS%*++~m/()), while the corresponding portion of field_content has lowercase characters (%$ss%*++~m/()). This discrepancy is causing the index method to throw a ValueError.
The index method is case sensitive.
Convert to the lower case as shown below:
word_one, word_two = ['(/ %$ss%*++~m/()', 'ss?=)?=)()']
field_content = "5uz8439qvnhfruieoghbvui gfurieaogv ui(/ %$SS%*++~m/() 123456789651321654 'ss?=)?=)() 87788+#~~##+"

# Convert everything to lowercase for case-insensitive comparison
pos_word_one = field_content.lower().index(word_one.lower())
pos_word_two = field_content.index(word_two)  # No need to convert for word_two as it matches the case

print(pos_word_one)
print(pos_word_two)

Let me know of that helps.

Oh my goodness. A stupid typo which I did not saw was the mistake. Thank you so much. Sorry for the variable typo in my example. This anyway helped me to and make me happy that in general my approach worked. Thanks again
